# Neo4J query for related users

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, spring-data-neo4j

I have the following example in Neo4J where users are interested in each other. There are two connections as each user can individually set a weight factor and some users may not be mutually interested in each other.

[image]

I want to write a Cypher query that retrieves related users for a user but also tells me which users are connected.

For example for user Fred, return Tom, Jane and also return that Jane is interested in Tom. Bob and Sarah should not be returned.

Here is what I have so far:

```
MATCH (u:User)-[r1:INTERESTED_IN]->(u2:User)
WHERE u.emailAddress ='fred@mail.com'
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[r2:INTERESTED_IN]->(u3:User)
OPTIONAL MATCH (u2)-[r3:INTERESTED_IN]->(u3)
RETURN u, r1, u2, r2, u3, r3
```

Is that along the right lines? I want to map this to a Spring Neo4J repository method but want to make sure that the query is correct and I'll be able to navigate the object graph to bring out the information above.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may do what you want:

```
MATCH (u:User)-[:INTERESTED_IN]->(u2:User)
WHERE u.emailAddress = 'fred@mail.com'
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[:INTERESTED_IN]->(u3:User)<-[:INTERESTED_IN]-(u2)
RETURN u, u2, COLLECT(u3) AS mutualInterests
```

It returns in each result row an interest of `u` (i.e., `u2`), along with their mutual interests.

Comment: Thank you. I added the relationships to the return as they contain properties. I also was able to map this directly into Spring Neo4J as a repository method and extract the values correctly. Cheers cybersam.